# Ubuntu 16.04 randomly freezes at boot

Tags: 16.04, boot

I have a Dell laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 preinstalled. I have been using it for months without having any major problems.

But today, when booting I was welcommed by this screen.

[image: ubuntu 16.04 freeze boot dell]

Aparently, it is freezed, because nothing happens no matter how long I wait or what key I press. I have to mention that this is not the first time when this problem occurs. It started about about a week ago manifesting randomly. I "solved" the problem by simply pressing the power button several times in the hope that it will eventually boot "correctly" (which it deed).

But this time, that method doesn't seem to work.

I did a quick search on the Internet but couldn't find the solution.

I tryied the following:

- booting while pressing SHIFT key (once the right one and once the left one)

- pressing F1 at boot

- pressing F12 at boot

- pressing the rest of the F keys immediatelly after the power button

All these maneuvers had no effect. But with one exception: when booting while pressing the F12 key, I noticed that the text on screen saying "F12 Boot Options" seems to be whiter as if it were "selected" or "highlighted" somehow.

I have to mention that about a week ago, while working on the computer I noticed the aparition of a new window informing me about some new updates. I was buzy at time and had no time for checking on that info. I postponed the update and then totally forgot about it and shut down the PC. I wasn't preoccupied by it because I update periodically. However, the next morning marked the first case of such "freeze".

Now it's been an hour since I am starring at this screen, so patience doesn't seem to be a solution.

I run out of ideas. What do you advice me to do next in order to get pass this screen and how to prevent it from repeating in the future?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware issue rather than an Ubuntu one. 2 things you can try to start with. Remove any **external drives**. Start up your laptop and keep tapping the F2 button quickly to see if you can reach BIOS/UEFI screen. Try several times from start-up if you can't reach it. If that still doesn't happen, disable your hard drive and then try again to reach BIOS.

Comment: Thank you! You are a life saver!  I don't have any external hard disk attached to the laptop, but your comment gave me the idea that it might be an USB-related problem. More exactly, that I should not have ANY external device plugged-in, not only the external hard disk. And yes, I do have a device! It's a fancy USB hub which I like to keep on my desk because it shows some Physics tricks when powered on. Silly thing if you think more about it. I unplugged the USB hub and then booted. And now it worked! So the cause of the problem was an external device after all! Thank you! +Paul Benson